# Is it possible to create a window page with checkboxes in NSIS?

Tags: checkbox, installation, nsis

I'd like to give the user the option of installing a custom selection of 4 apps.

Is it therefore possible to add a page to an NSIS installer that contains 4 checkboxes? This could then be used to create if statements based on the selection and install the selected apps.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The easy solution is to just use the components page:

```
InstallDir $ProgramFiles\MyAppCollection
Page Components
Page InstFiles

Section "App 1"
SetOutPath $InstDir\App1
File app1.exe
SectionEnd

Section "App 2"
SetOutPath $InstDir\app2
File app2.exe
SectionEnd
```

Use the [nsDialogs plug-in](https://nsis.sourceforge.io/Docs/nsDialogs/Readme.html) if you want to create a custom page. In the pages leave function you could use NSD_GetState to get the checkbox state and the Macros from Sections.nsh to toggle a hidden section.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Would each section be able to have its own uninstaller however?

Comment: There are many ways to do that I guess. 1 The same components style. 2 Detect on command line. 3 Call writeuninstaller multiple times and add tag data to the end like https://nsis.sourceforge.io/ReadCustomerData 4 Actually build and bundle separate installers/uninstallers.